# Wrong date format in Kendo Grid

Tags: kendo-ui, kendo-grid, date-formatting

```
I have a kendo grid,

@(Html.Kendo().Grid<TaskViewModel>()
    .Name("grid")
    .Deferred()
    .ClientRowTemplate(Html.Partial("Partials/TaskGridRowTemplate").ToHtmlString())
    .TableHtmlAttributes(new { @class = "table table-stripped" })
    .Events(e => e.DataBound("setCdsPriority"))
    .Columns(columns =>
    {
        columns.Bound(e => e.IsSelected)
            .Sortable(true)
            .Filterable(false)
            .Title(string.Empty);
        columns.Bound(e => e.ScanDate).Title("Scanning Date");   
...
    })

    .Filterable()
    .Selectable(selectable => selectable.Mode(GridSelectionMode.Multiple))
    .Sortable()
    .Pageable(x =>
    {
        x.ButtonCount(3);
        x.Enabled(true);
        x.PageSizes(new[] { "5", "10", "20" });
        x.Refresh(true);
    })

    .DataSource(dataSource => dataSource
        .Ajax()
        .Read(read => read.Action("AllTasks", "Cockpit"))
        .ServerOperation(true)
      ))
```

And I have to filter it as you can see in the image

[image]

This is the method that does the filter

```
 public List<TaskViewModel> GetTasksFiltered(TaskFilterModel filters)
        {
            List<Task> tasks = service.GetTasksFiltered(MapperExtension.CreateMapper<TaskFilterModel, TaskFilter>(filters));

            return tasks.Select(Convert).ToList();
        }
```

This is the method that returns the results to the view

```
public JsonResult AllTasksFiltered(TaskFilterModel filters)
        {
            return Json(taskModelFactory.GetTasksFiltered(filters), JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
    }
```

And this is my ajax

```
function onClickSearch() {
        var filtersObject =
        {
            CurrentWorkflowStepId: $("#taskStatus").data("kendoDropDownList").value(),
            ScanFromDate: $("#scanFromDate").data("kendoDatePicker").value(),
            ScanToDate: $("#scanToDate").data("kendoDatePicker").value(),
            BusinessCase: $("#businessCase").data("kendoDropDownList").value(),
            Region: $("#region").data("kendoDropDownList").value(),
            ZR: $("#zr").val()
        }

        $.ajax({
            type: "PUT",
            url: "/Cockpit/AllTasksFiltered",
            dataType: "json",
            traditional: true,
            data: JSON.stringify(filtersObject),
            contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
            success: function (data) {
                $("#grid").data("kendoGrid").setDataSource(new kendo.data.DataSource({
                    data: data
                }));
            }
        });
    }
```

When the grid is first loaded, the Scanning Date column is ok.

This is the row template bit for the scanning date

```
 <td>
        #: kendo.toString(ScanDate, 'dd.MM.yyyy HH:mm')#
    </td>
```

When I do a search, the date that is displayed is

```
/Date(1498558275437)/
```

The date has the right format before being displayed, but I get this strange format on screen.

Any ideas?
Tks in advance.

Comment: http://www.telerik.com/forums/date-format-is-lost-when-manually-populating-datasource-in-jquery#ue3JdeBl_0yv_H7ZxQav2Q This is not exactly what you are doing but the problem is the same.  Why don't you use  ServerFiltering and pass your filter object to your Read action using the Data() configuration?

Comment: replace _columns.Bound(e => e.ScanDate).Title("Scanning Date");_ by this _columns.Bound(e => e.ScanDate).Format("{0:dd.MM.yyyy HH:mm}");_ . hope it helps